# How to get the cheapest product for each product type of each company?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I previously listed the valid offers using:

```html
SELECT
    pt.prod_type_description 'Tipo do Produto',
    p.prod_brand 'Marca',
    c.comp_fantasy_name 'Nome da Empresa',
    o.offer_price 'Preco'
FROM offer                  AS o
    INNER JOIN company      AS c ON o.comp_id = c.comp_id
    INNER JOIN product      AS p ON o.prod_id = p.prod_id
    INNER JOIN product_type AS pt ON p.prod_type_id = pt.prod_type_id
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, o.offer_expired_at, 23) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.datetimeBrasilia(), 23)
GROUP BY pt.prod_type_id, o.offer_price, p.prod_id, c.comp_fantasy_name, pt.prod_type_description, p.prod_brand, o.offer_id
```

But my question is how to get the cheapest product (without importance by the brand) of each type of product of each company?

```html
TYPE PRODUCT    |     BRAND     |   COMPANY     |   PRICE
----------------------------------------------------------
Cimento             Cauê     MAConstuc     13.65
Areia             AB Areias     MAConstuc     15.79
Brita             Briforte     MAConstuc     21.30
Paver PaviS     MotriX     MAConstuc     0.65
Paver Raquete     Forten     TilJola     1.20
Cimento             Votoran     TilJola     10.40
Cimento             Cauê     TilJola     14.65
Areia             AB Areias     TilJola     11.56
Brita             Briforte     TilJola      9.99
Paver PaviS     MotriX     TilJola      1.30
Paver Raquete     Forten     TilJola      1.00
Cimento             Votoran     KiCalc     22.90
Cimento             Cauê     KiCalc     20.00
Areia             AB Areias     KiCalc     18.30
Brita             Briforte     KiCalc     17.00
Paver PaviS     MotriX     KiCalc      1.35
Paver Raquete     Forten     KiCalc      0.99
```

```html
-- example of company TilJola (without Cimento Cauê)
Cimento             Votoran         TilJola         10.40
Areia             AB Areias         TilJola         11.56
Paver PaviS     MotriX         TilJola         1.30
Paver Raquete     Forten         TilJola         1.00

-- example of company KiCalc (without Cimento Votoran)
Cimento             Cauê         KiCalc         20.00
Areia             AB Areias         KiCalc         18.30
Brita             Briforte         KiCalc         17.00
Paver PaviS     MotriX         KiCalc         1.35
Paver Raquete     Forten         KiCalc         0.99
```

previously I have listed the valid offers using:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this structure for the query, the simplest method is window functions in the `order by` with `top (1) with ties`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       pt.prod_type_description as [Tipo do Produto],
       p.prod_brand as Marca,
       c.comp_fantasy_name as [Nome da Empresa],
       o.offer_price as Preco
FROM offer        o JOIN
     company      c
     ON o.comp_id = c.comp_id JOIN
     product      p
     ON o.prod_id = p.prod_id JOIN
     product_type pt
     ON p.prod_type_id = pt.prod_type_id
WHERE offer_expired_at >= dbo.datetimeBrasilia()
GROUP BY pt.prod_type_id, o.offer_price, p.prod_id, c.comp_fantasy_name, pt.prod_type_description, p.prod_brand, o.offer_id
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pt.prod_type_description, pt.comp_fantasy_name ORDER BY o.offer_price);
```

Notes some other changes to your query:

- Dates should be compared as dates and not strings.
- In SQL Server, you should never use `VARCHAR` without a length.  The length varies by context and fixing problems caused by not having a length can be really hard to debug.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  If you start using them for column names, you'll eventually make a mistake.
- I only use `as` for column aliases and never for table aliases.  Admittedly, this is just a preference, but I think it minimizes the chances of errors (particularly leaving a comma out of the `select`.

Comment: I used the date comparison using string because the function does not want to compare date and time, but only the date

Comment: @EduardoSpagna . . . Then cast the two values to a date.  Don't convert to data types for such a comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I found your code very good. But I'm still unsure how to return the cheapest kind of product (just one of each, eliminating products with the same type) grouped by company, just like the examples I cited as well. If you can give me an idea about this

Comment: I joined your idea with the comment below and it worked exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()` function

```
select * from 
(
SELECT
    pt.prod_type_description 'Tipo do Produto',
    p.prod_brand 'Marca',
    c.comp_fantasy_name 'Nome da Empresa',
    o.offer_price 'Preco',
 row_number() over(partition by c.comp_fantasy_name,pt.prod_type_description order by o.offer_price) as rn
FROM offer                  AS o
    INNER JOIN company      AS c ON o.comp_id = c.comp_id
    INNER JOIN product      AS p ON o.prod_id = p.prod_id
    INNER JOIN product_type AS pt ON p.prod_type_id = pt.prod_type_id
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, o.offer_expired_at, 23) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.datetimeBrasilia(), 23)
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: I joined your idea with the above comment and it worked exactly what I wanted. Thank you!